Can science explain the anomalous properties of water?
According to proponents of the so-called Intelligent Design (for example, here, here, and here), the unique properties of water that allow for the existence of life cannot be explained by science and point to the existence of an intelligent designer. Is that true?

My DV is for your misrepresenting the purpose of the first paper. It does not claim science can't explain the properties of water; it actually explains the science of water and its unique nature quite well, which allows for life as we know it to exist. The flaw in the paper is a common one: teleological thinking, i.e. that the end result is the purpose for the end result (e.g. giraffes developed long necks so they can eat with less competition.) I didn't bother to read the others.

Please provide a direct quote supporting the claim. (Please also provide a clear unambiguous claim to be tested).

Voted to close - as anongoodnurse commented, the question is fallacious in its assumptions

The third link appears to be to a blank page. I think the OP should read the puddle quote from Douglas Adams.

@WeatherVane The third link just has a trailing underscore that shouldn't be there. Remove it and it points to a pdf, which I won't download anyway. Not worth editing to fix that link though; I think the question is not salvageable anyway.

It is absolutely not true that "anomalous" properties of water cannot be explained by science.
If you meant to ask whether the fact that the properties of water are exactly those that support life is indicative of an intelligent creator, that is an entirely different question.

The main 'anomalous' property of water is that the solid (ice) floats in the liquid. The problem is that this is not unique to water at all. Various elements (including Si and Pu) exhibit this behavior as well.

...and science has good explanations for this and the other "anomalous" properties.

Science has no special problems explaining why water has the properties that it does.
Two replies to "isn't it a bit suss that these are exactly what you need to sustain life?" are
1 - what else would you expect to see, given that you are alive and conscious, than a universe that can support life and consciousness?
2 - How could water have been "designed" differently? It has the properties it does as a result of physical laws that apply to everything. It's not like nature has some sort of exceptional tweaks in play, that apply just to water and nothing else,  which likely were put in place by a designer.

Please don't answer poorly asked questions. When you do answer, please provide linked references, not just arguments.
